# How to change status of dlfileentry in liferay 6.2

Tags: liferay

Iam adding a file to folder by this way

```
if(fileExisits(folderId, title))
{
    fileEntry=DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil.getFileEntry(repositoryId, folderId, title);
    serviceContext.setWorkflowAction(0);                
    DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil.updateFileEntry(userId, fileEntry.getFileEntryId(), sourceFileName, mimeType, title, description, changeLog, true, fileEntry.getFileEntryTypeId(), null, null, is, size, serviceContext);
}
else
{
    serviceContext.setWorkflowAction(0);
    DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil.addFileEntry(userId, repositoryId, repositoryId, folderId, sourceFileName, mimeType, title, description, changeLog, 0, null, null, is, size, serviceContext);
}
```

But even though it is updating or creating a `dlfile` it is being saved as draft.

Can anyone please help me how to change the status of dlfile programaticaly.

Comment: this may be helpful [folder-and-file-upload](http://liferayiseasy.blogspot.in/2015/07/folder-and-file-upload-programmatically.html)

Comment: You can use `DLAppServiceUtil.addFileEntry` and `DLAppServiceUtil.updateFileEntry` respectively as used by `Documents and Media` portlet itself.

Comment: See `EditFileEntryAction.updateFileEntry` method for further details.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try `serviceContext.setWorkflowAction(WorkflowConstants.ACTION_PUBLISH)`

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution i was adding user and group to servicecontext now instead iam using new ServiceContext() . By doing so iam able to create as dlfile with approvied status